# How to integrate Nagios in .net project?

Tags: nagios

How to integrate  Nagios in .net project ?
i am new to  Nagios.can someone guide me to the step by step process to integrate  Nagios in .net project

Comment: There's not really enough information here to answer. How do you want to "integrate" it?

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is to use Nagios Plugin NDOUTILS which will insert nagios monitered data into MYSQL database, from mysql u can generate reports.